# kernel Local crashes during the course of a For loop

Tags: evaluation, kernel, crash

I want to find the minimum of the function `r[x,p]` subject to the constraint `w[x,p,t]==0` (`t` is a fixed parameter).
To find the minimum I use the function `NMinimize`.

The constraint `w[x,p,t]==0` is a rather complicated numerical function. It depends on the function `evolve[x,p,t]` which is the numerical solution of some ordinary differential equation.

I use a `For` loop to find the minima for different values of the constraint parameter `t`.

My problem is the following: At certain instants of time, the kernel Local quits without errors or warnings before the loop is finished. The error message is "The kernel Local has quit (exited) during the course of an evaluation". The time when the kernel quits is always different, sometimes it happens very early, sometimes rather late. When I evaluate `NMinimize` for the parameter `t` where the kernel crashed (and also for parameters beyond that point), it works well without any error.

First I thought the reason for the crash could be a lack of memory, but if I monitor the memory during the calculation, everything looks fine.

Here is the code of a simplified version of my problem.

```
(*definition of the constraint*)
h[x_, p_] := -x^2 + p^2 + x^4;

evolve[ xini_, pini_, time_] := 
 Module[{x, p, t}, 
  Hold[{x[time], p[time]} /. 
   NDSolve[{x'[t] == p[t], p'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == xini, p[0] == pini}, {x, p}, 
           {t, 0, time}, MaxSteps -> Infinity][[1]]
 ]];

w[x_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := h @@ ReleaseHold[evolve[x, p, t]] - h[x, p];

(*definition of the function which should be minimized*)
r[x_, p_] := {x - 1, p}.{{0.1, 0}, {0, 0.1}}.{x - 1, p};

fct = First[{Print[#]; 
 NMinimize[{r[x, p], w[x, p, #] == 0}, {x, p}, 
  Method -> "NelderMead", MaxIterations -> 10^3]}] &;

(*loop over different parameters t*)
dt := 0.05;
tmin := 0;
tmax := 40;
maxt := Floor[(tmax - tmin)/dt];
times = Table[tmin + dt*n, {n, 0, maxt}];

positions = Table[0, {Length[times]}];
values = Table[0, {Length[times]}];

For[n = 1, n <= Length[times], n++,
  tmp = fct@times[[n]];
  positions[[n]] = {x, p} /. (tmp[[2]]);
  values[[n]] = tmp[[1]];
];
```

When I replace the loop over `t` by

```
fct/@times;
```

I get the same error.

I am using *Mathematica* 9.0.1.0

Comment: I can repro it here

Comment: Random suggestion, but I once had a similar problem which was solved when I used readyboost on a large usb stick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The random crashing of the kernel seems to arise due to your definition of `evolve` and `fct`.
I'll keep

```
h[x_, p_] := -x^2 + p^2 + x^4;
```

and change the definition of `evolve` to

```
evolve[xini_, pini_, time_] := 
 Module[{x, p}, 
  Hold[{x[time], p[time]} /. 
   First@NDSolve[{x'[t] == p[t], p'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == xini, p[0] == pini}, 
                 {x, p}, {t, 0, time}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]
  ]];
```

as the `t` you put into `Module` might occasionally collide with the `t` inside `NDSolve`, although it shouldn't.
The following definitions are kept unchanged

```
w[x_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ, time_?NumericQ] := h @@ ReleaseHold[evolve[x, p, time]] - h[x, p];
r[x_, p_] := {x - 1, p}.{{0.1, 0}, {0, 0.1}}.{x - 1, p};
```

and [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html?q=Set)(`=`) instead of [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`) is used for

```
dt = 0.05;
tmin = 0;
tmax = 40;
maxt = Floor[(tmax - tmin)/dt];
times = Table[tmin + dt*n, {n, 0, maxt}];
```

just because it is more appropriate.
Your definition of `fct` looks a little strange to me. But I guess the purposse of this construction is to monitor the progress of the calculation, while having the result as the output, and you simply misused the curly braces for lists, where you should have used parentheses for grouping (see [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheFourKindsOfBracketingInTheWolframLanguage.html)):

```
fct = (Print[#];
       NMinimize[{r[x, p], w[x, p, #] == 0}, {x, p}, 
                  Method -> "NelderMead", MaxIterations -> 10^3]) &;
```

Unfortunately the kernel still crashes occasionally when `fct`is mapped over `times` (`fct/@times`) and it is not clear what causes this buggy behavior. 
However, an easy way to deal with it and at the same time speeding up the calculation significantly (more than 3.5 times on my 4 core PC) is to use `ParallelMap`:

```
results = ParallelMap[fct, times, Method -> "FinestGrained"];
```

The `values` and `positions` can then be extracted using

```
values = results[[All, 1]];
positions = {x, p} /. results[[All, 2]];
```

and plotted with

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{times, values}], PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"time", "value"}]
```

> [image: ValuesPlot]

and

```
ListPlot[positions, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "p"}]
```

> [image: xpPlot]

or

```
ListPlot[{Transpose[{times, First@Transpose[positions]}], 
          Transpose[{times, Last@Transpose[positions]}]}, 
          PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
          FrameLabel -> {"time"}, PlotLegends -> {"x", "p"}]
```

> [image: xptimePlot]

---

But why is the kernel crashing using `Map` and how can `ParallelMap` still successfully perform the calculations?

As the messages

> ```
> LinkObject::linkd: Unable to communicate with closed link LinkObject["C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\MathKernel" -subkernel -noinit -mathlink -noicon,331,6]. >>
> KernelObject::rdead: Subkernel connected through KernelObject[3,local] appears dead. >>
> ```

reveal, the *Subkernels* still crash at random frequency due to a lost connection.
But fortunately, the *Masterkernel* keeps running and is requeueing the failed calculation properly and therefore enables a successfull completion of the calculations:

> ```
> Parallel`Developer`QueueRun::req: Requeueing evaluations {11} assigned to KernelObject[3,local,<defunct>].
> LaunchKernels::clone: Kernel KernelObject[3,local,<defunct>] resurrected as KernelObject[5,local]. >>
> ```

Comment: Reported to wolfram support.